# Как подключить "стороннюю" библиотеку в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку http://librtf.sourceforge.net/
для работы с текстом на С++ - не получается. Делаю это через заголовочный файл, хотя слышал что можно через Visual Studio 2010 библиотеку подключить, а в Qt она будет как встроенная/

Вот файл main.cpp

```
  #include <QCoreApplication>
  //#include "librtf.h"
  #include <librtf.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

      librtf lib;
      lib.DoSomething();

      return a.exec();
  }
```

Файл ecsperim.pro

```
 QT       += core

 QT       -= gui

 TARGET = ecsperim
 CONFIG   += console
 CONFIG   -= app_bundle

 TEMPLATE = apps


 SOURCES += main.cpp

 #INCLUDEPATH += C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3//
 #LIBS += C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3// -COPYING.LIB
 INCLUDEPATH += C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3//
 #LIBS += -L. C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3// -COPYING.LIB
 #INCLUDEPATH += C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3//
 #LIBS += C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3// -copying
 #LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/libraries/librtf-0.0.3/librtf.lib"
 #LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/libraries/librtf-0.0.3/COPYING.LIB"
 #LIBS += "C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3//COPYING.LIB"
 LIBS += "C://Program Files//Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0//libraries//librtf-0.0.3//copyng.lib"

 #LIBS += "-LC:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/libraries/librtf-0.0.3" -lrtf
```

Произвожу сборку у он мне выдает :

```
 NMAKE:-1: ошибка: U1052: не найден файл "Makefile.Release"
 NMAKE:-1: ошибка: U1077: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
```

Что делать, как быть ????

> Опишите-ка, пожалуйста все Ваши условия. В чем собираете свой проект - VS или QtCreator, собрана ли библиотека (можно вывод dir для каталога librtf-0.0.3) .

Собираю в QtCreator , на счет собрана ли библиотека так я открыл фаил и там было написано что все готово, я (в cmd чето потыкал и все и то она команды не понимала) в общем думаю что нет , но я даже не понял надо ли ее в обще собирать.

Comment: Как именно не получается надо бы описать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Как обычно, курить мануалы :)
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Вы должны указать, при помощи LIBS, не просто путь, но библиотеку, с которой нужно слинковаться, а не просто путь до исходников.
В случае Windows, можно использовать Unix стиль, то есть

```
LIBS += "-LC:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/libraries/librtf-0.0.3" -lrtf
```

Или же просто,

```
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/libraries/librtf-0.0.3/librtf.lib"
```

Смущает указание Вами некоего "-copying"

Но, самое главное, нужно предварительно собрать указанную Вами библиотеку. Или найти пресобранную для Windows

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но чтото не вышло ."-copying" это сама библиотека

Comment: Запостите вывод компилятора

Comment: Запостил вывод .

Comment: Вывод Ваш воообще в "другую сторону", бишь не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Сами видите?
Опишите-ка, пожалуйста все Ваши условия. В чем собираете свой проект - VS или QtCreator, собрана ли библиотека (можно вывод dir для каталога librtf-0.0.3)