# Подключение библиотеки в qt creator

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator

На ubuntu установлена библиотека GStreamer. Хочу подключить ее к своему проекту в Qt Creator но не знаю как, библиотека была загружена через консоль.

Comment: так а пользуетесь чем? cmake, qt, просто make?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch qmake

Comment: укажите эту инфу в вопросе, в метках. Ну а по вопросу есть вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442828/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-qt - может поможет. Ну а вообще стоит перейти на `cmake` - `qmake` просто ужасен.